# select group before certain observations in R

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

Say

```
data=structure(list(x1 = c(88L, 88L, 94L, 82L, 68L, 72L, 43L, 84L, 
65L, 91L, 65L, 80L, 82L, 63L, 67L, 58L, 100L, 32L, 75L, 66L, 
30L, 12L, 97L, 58L, 14L, 64L), group = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("female", "male"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("x1", 
"group"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -26L))
```

In this data  there is group variable  (sex (male and female)
I need get statistics mean and 25 percentile for ALL male which go before female. Male which after female, i don't touch. Also female i don't touch.
So as output

```
x1  group   mean    25%
88  male    76,36   66,5
88  male    76,36   66,5
94  male    76,36   66,5
82  male    76,36   66,5
68  male    76,36   66,5
72  male    76,36   66,5
43  male    76,36   66,5
84  male    76,36   66,5
65  male    76,36   66,5
91  male    76,36   66,5
65  male    76,36   66,5
80  female      
82  female      
63  female      
67  female      
58  female      
100 female      
32  female      
75  male        
66  male        
30  male        
12  male        
97  male        
58  male        
14  male        
64  male
```

How to do it?

## edit

```
x1  group
88  male
88  male
94  male
82  male
68  male
72  male
43  male
84  male
65  male
91  male
65  male
80  female
82  female
63  female
67  female
58  female
100 female
32  female
**76,36 male
**76,36 male
30  male
12  male
**76,36 male
58  male
14  male
64  male
```

here result.

Comment: @SaurabhChauhan it is 25 percentile

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)

data %>%
  group_by(group, group2 = rleid(group)) %>%                       # group by gender and it's position
  mutate(MEAN = mean(x1[group=="male" & group2==1]),               # calculate metrics only for male in position 1
         Q25 = quantile(x1[group=="male" & group2==1], 0.25)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%                                                    # ungroup
  select(-group2) %>%                                              # remove column
  data.frame()                                                     # only for visualisation purposes

#     x1  group     MEAN  Q25
# 1   88   male 76.36364 66.5
# 2   88   male 76.36364 66.5
# 3   94   male 76.36364 66.5
# 4   82   male 76.36364 66.5
# 5   68   male 76.36364 66.5
# 6   72   male 76.36364 66.5
# 7   43   male 76.36364 66.5
# 8   84   male 76.36364 66.5
# 9   65   male 76.36364 66.5
# 10  91   male 76.36364 66.5
# 11  65   male 76.36364 66.5
# 12  80 female      NaN   NA
# 13  82 female      NaN   NA
# 14  63 female      NaN   NA
# 15  67 female      NaN   NA
# 16  58 female      NaN   NA
# 17 100 female      NaN   NA
# 18  32 female      NaN   NA
# 19  75   male      NaN   NA
# 20  66   male      NaN   NA
# 21  30   male      NaN   NA
# 22  12   male      NaN   NA
# 23  97   male      NaN   NA
# 24  58   male      NaN   NA
# 25  14   male      NaN   NA
# 26  64   male      NaN   NA
```

For updating `x1` column according to the logic you mentioned you can use this:

```
data %>%
  group_by(group, group2 = rleid(group)) %>%                       
  mutate(MEAN = mean(x1[group=="male" & group2==1]),               
         Q25 = quantile(x1[group=="male" & group2==1], 0.25)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(x1 = ifelse(group=="male" & group2==3 & x1 > unique(Q25[!is.na(Q25)]), unique(MEAN[!is.na(MEAN)]), x1)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-group2) %>%
  data.frame()

#     x1  group     MEAN  Q25
# 1   88.00000   male 76.36364 66.5
# 2   88.00000   male 76.36364 66.5
# 3   94.00000   male 76.36364 66.5
# 4   82.00000   male 76.36364 66.5
# 5   68.00000   male 76.36364 66.5
# 6   72.00000   male 76.36364 66.5
# 7   43.00000   male 76.36364 66.5
# 8   84.00000   male 76.36364 66.5
# 9   65.00000   male 76.36364 66.5
# 10  91.00000   male 76.36364 66.5
# 11  65.00000   male 76.36364 66.5
# 12  80.00000 female      NaN   NA
# 13  82.00000 female      NaN   NA
# 14  63.00000 female      NaN   NA
# 15  67.00000 female      NaN   NA
# 16  58.00000 female      NaN   NA
# 17 100.00000 female      NaN   NA
# 18  32.00000 female      NaN   NA
# 19  76.36364   male      NaN   NA
# 20  66.00000   male      NaN   NA
# 21  30.00000   male      NaN   NA
# 22  12.00000   male      NaN   NA
# 23  76.36364   male      NaN   NA
# 24  58.00000   male      NaN   NA
# 25  14.00000   male      NaN   NA
# 26  64.00000   male      NaN   NA
```

The extra piece of code I added (`mutate`) updates `x1` only for males after females (i.e. `group2 = 3') and only if`x1` is bigger than the quantile value.

Comment: thank you it is work. May i ask you edit code in term of? "if for male that go after female value by x1 < than 25 percentile, which we calculated for male ***before female***, then this value must be replaced by mean for male ***before female***   "  Female category we dont' touch. Do you understand me?

Comment: Can you give me a quick example? Is it something like row 7 you want 43 to become 76.36?

Comment: i edited post, please check it. only three value by x1 for male after female  more than 25 percentile for male before female, so it replaced on mean for male before female. I made a typo. if for male that go after female value by x1 >(more) than 25 percentile. , which we calculated for male before female.Sorry. **i marked replaced value.

Comment: Ok, I'll have a look. What happens if you have male - female - male - female - male? Is that possible?

Comment: @ AntoniosK,  the biggst thank you , may i ask you help in related topic  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51970403/select-group-before-certain-observations-separated-by-grouping-var-in-r. Here i want to do this analysis but for x and y group separately.

Answer (score 4):

In `data.table`, you can edit the rows where `rleid(group) == 1` i.e. the first group of rows, grouped by value of `group`.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)

df[rleid(group) == 1, `:=`(mean = mean(x1), Q25 = quantile(x1, 0.25))]
```

Result

```
#      x1  group     mean  Q25
#  1:  88   male 76.36364 66.5
#  2:  88   male 76.36364 66.5
#  3:  94   male 76.36364 66.5
#  4:  82   male 76.36364 66.5
#  5:  68   male 76.36364 66.5
#  6:  72   male 76.36364 66.5
#  7:  43   male 76.36364 66.5
#  8:  84   male 76.36364 66.5
#  9:  65   male 76.36364 66.5
# 10:  91   male 76.36364 66.5
# 11:  65   male 76.36364 66.5
# 12:  80 female       NA   NA
# 13:  82 female       NA   NA
# 14:  63 female       NA   NA
# 15:  67 female       NA   NA
# 16:  58 female       NA   NA
# 17: 100 female       NA   NA
# 18:  32 female       NA   NA
# 19:  75   male       NA   NA
# 20:  66   male       NA   NA
# 21:  30   male       NA   NA
# 22:  12   male       NA   NA
# 23:  97   male       NA   NA
# 24:  58   male       NA   NA
# 25:  14   male       NA   NA
# 26:  64   male       NA   NA
#      x1  group     mean  Q25
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative `dplyr` approach which summarises by `rleid()` group and uses a `left_join()` to append the result columns:

```
library(dplyr)
result <- data %>% 
  group_by(rleid = data.table::rleid(group)) %>% 
  left_join(., filter(., rleid == 1) %>% 
              summarise(mean = mean(x1), q25 = quantile(x1, 0.25))
  ) %>% 
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-rleid)
result %>% 
  print(n = Inf)   # make sure to print all rows
```

> ```
> # A tibble: 26 x 4
>       x1 group   mean   q25
>    <int> <fct>  <dbl> <dbl>
>  1    88 male    76.4  66.5
>  2    88 male    76.4  66.5
>  3    94 male    76.4  66.5
>  4    82 male    76.4  66.5
>  5    68 male    76.4  66.5
>  6    72 male    76.4  66.5
>  7    43 male    76.4  66.5
>  8    84 male    76.4  66.5
>  9    65 male    76.4  66.5
> 10    91 male    76.4  66.5
> 11    65 male    76.4  66.5
> 12    80 female  NA    NA  
> 13    82 female  NA    NA  
> 14    63 female  NA    NA  
> 15    67 female  NA    NA  
> 16    58 female  NA    NA  
> 17   100 female  NA    NA  
> 18    32 female  NA    NA  
> 19    75 male    NA    NA  
> 20    66 male    NA    NA  
> 21    30 male    NA    NA  
> 22    12 male    NA    NA  
> 23    97 male    NA    NA  
> 24    58 male    NA    NA  
> 25    14 male    NA    NA  
> 26    64 male    NA    NA
> ```

Note that `data` is *not* modified unless the result is assigned back to `data`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is also an alternative `data.table` approach which answers OP's original question as well as the additional question raised by the OP in comments [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51967572/select-group-before-certain-observations-in-r/52036210#comment90886471_51967896) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51967572/select-group-before-certain-observations-in-r/52036210#comment90887365_51967896).

For both questions we need to compute the aggregates for the first group of males and then update  `data` *by reference* through an *update join* for the first question and an *update non-equi join* for the second question.

#### Compute aggregates for first group of males

```
library(data.table)
# coerce to data.table, append rleid for later joins
setDT(data)[, rleid := rleid(group)][
  # ensure that x1 has the same type as mean(x1)
  , x1 := as.double(x1)]
agg <- data[rleid == 1, .(mean(x1), quantile(x1, .25)), by = rleid]
agg
```

> ```
>    rleid       V1   V2
> 1:     1 76.36364 66.5
> ```

#### Original question: Append statistics for first male group

This is achieved by an update join

```
data[agg, on = "rleid", c("mean", "q25") := .(V1, V2)]
data[]
```

> ```
>      x1  group rleid     mean  q25
>  1:  88   male     1 76.36364 66.5
>  2:  88   male     1 76.36364 66.5
>  3:  94   male     1 76.36364 66.5
>  4:  82   male     1 76.36364 66.5
>  5:  68   male     1 76.36364 66.5
>  6:  72   male     1 76.36364 66.5
>  7:  43   male     1 76.36364 66.5
>  8:  84   male     1 76.36364 66.5
>  9:  65   male     1 76.36364 66.5
> 10:  91   male     1 76.36364 66.5
> 11:  65   male     1 76.36364 66.5
> 12:  80 female     2       NA   NA
> 13:  82 female     2       NA   NA
> 14:  63 female     2       NA   NA
> 15:  67 female     2       NA   NA
> 16:  58 female     2       NA   NA
> 17: 100 female     2       NA   NA
> 18:  32 female     2       NA   NA
> 19:  75   male     3       NA   NA
> 20:  66   male     3       NA   NA
> 21:  30   male     3       NA   NA
> 22:  12   male     3       NA   NA
> 23:  97   male     3       NA   NA
> 24:  58   male     3       NA   NA
> 25:  14   male     3       NA   NA
> 26:  64   male     3       NA   NA
>      x1  group rleid     mean  q25
> ```

Note that `data` has been updated by reference, i.e., without copying.

#### Additional question: Modify selected values in second male group

The OP has requested to replace any `x1` value in the *second male* group which exceeds the 25 percent quantile `q25` computed for the *first male* group by the mean computed for the first male group. Note that the *second male* group is identified by `rleid == 3L` as the female group comes in between.

This can be achieved by an *update non-equi join*. The join condition selects only those rows which belong to `rleid == 3L` and where `x1` is greater `q25`.

```
data[agg[, .(rleid = 3, V1, V2)], on = .(rleid, x1 > V2), x1 := V1][]
# remove helper column no longer needed
data[, rleid := NULL]
data[]
```

> ```
>            x1  group     mean  q25
>  1:  88.00000   male 76.36364 66.5
>  2:  88.00000   male 76.36364 66.5
>  3:  94.00000   male 76.36364 66.5
>  4:  82.00000   male 76.36364 66.5
>  5:  68.00000   male 76.36364 66.5
>  6:  72.00000   male 76.36364 66.5
>  7:  43.00000   male 76.36364 66.5
>  8:  84.00000   male 76.36364 66.5
>  9:  65.00000   male 76.36364 66.5
> 10:  91.00000   male 76.36364 66.5
> 11:  65.00000   male 76.36364 66.5
> 12:  80.00000 female       NA   NA
> 13:  82.00000 female       NA   NA
> 14:  63.00000 female       NA   NA
> 15:  67.00000 female       NA   NA
> 16:  58.00000 female       NA   NA
> 17: 100.00000 female       NA   NA
> 18:  32.00000 female       NA   NA
> 19:  76.36364   male       NA   NA
> 20:  66.00000   male       NA   NA
> 21:  30.00000   male       NA   NA
> 22:  12.00000   male       NA   NA
> 23:  76.36364   male       NA   NA
> 24:  58.00000   male       NA   NA
> 25:  14.00000   male       NA   NA
> 26:  64.00000   male       NA   NA
>            x1  group     mean  q25
> ```

Please, note that rows 19 and 23 have been updated as requested. Again, `data` is updated by reference.