# select group before certain observations separated by grouping var in R

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

in the continuation of this topic
[select group before certain observations in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51967572/select-group-before-certain-observations-in-r)
I have grouping var -`add` (x or y)

```
    data=structure(list(add = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("x", 
"y"), class = "factor"), x1 = c(14L, 15L, 36L, 53L, 95L, 56L, 
53L, 10L, 39L, 27L, 67L, 25L, 19L, 49L, 53L, 64L, 61L, 12L, 75L, 
34L, 88L, 43L, 85L, 93L, 44L, 31L, 37L, 90L, 66L, 39L, 59L, 96L, 
41L, 23L, 20L, 26L, 69L, 28L, 35L, 96L, 87L, 82L, 70L, 68L, 26L, 
12L, 58L, 18L, 76L, 93L, 3L, 31L), group = structure(c(2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L), .Label = c("female", "male"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("add", 
"x1", "group"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -52L))
```

how this analysis split by group?

The solutuion of AntoniosK is very good

```
library(tidyverse)
library(data.table)

data %>%
  group_by(group, group2 = rleid(group)) %>%                       
  mutate(MEAN = mean(x1[group=="male" & group2==1]),               
         Q25 = quantile(x1[group=="male" & group2==1], 0.25)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(x1 = ifelse(group=="male" & group2==3 & x1 > unique(Q25[!is.na(Q25)]), unique(MEAN[!is.na(MEAN)]), x1)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-group2) %>%
  data.frame()
```

but if i want for x and y group perform it separately. I do so

```
data %>% group_by(add) %>% 
  group_by(group, group2 = rleid(group)) %>%                       
  mutate(MEAN = mean(x1[group=="male" & group2==1]),               
         Q25 = quantile(x1[group=="male" & group2==1], 0.25)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(x1 = ifelse(group=="male" & group2==3 & x1 > unique(Q25[!is.na(Q25)]), unique(MEAN[!is.na(MEAN)]), x1)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-group2) %>%
  data.frame()
```

as the result incorrect statistics

```
   add       x1  group     MEAN   Q25
1    x 14.00000   male 46.86364 26.25
2    x 15.00000   male 46.86364 26.25
3    x 36.00000   male 46.86364 26.25
4    x 53.00000   male 46.86364 26.25
5    x 95.00000   male 46.86364 26.25
6    x 56.00000   male 46.86364 26.25
7    x 53.00000   male 46.86364 26.25
8    x 10.00000   male 46.86364 26.25
9    x 39.00000   male 46.86364 26.25
10   x 27.00000   male 46.86364 26.25
11   x 67.00000   male 46.86364 26.25
12   x 25.00000 female      NaN    NA
13   x 19.00000 female      NaN    NA
14   x 49.00000 female      NaN    NA
15   x 53.00000 female      NaN    NA
16   x 64.00000 female      NaN    NA
17   x 61.00000 female      NaN    NA
18   x 12.00000 female      NaN    NA
19   x 46.86364   male      NaN    NA
20   x 46.86364   male      NaN    NA
21   x 46.86364   male      NaN    NA
22   x 46.86364   male      NaN    NA
23   x 46.86364   male      NaN    NA
24   x 46.86364   male      NaN    NA
25   x 46.86364   male      NaN    NA
26   x 46.86364   male      NaN    NA
27   y 37.00000   male 46.86364 26.25
28   y 90.00000   male 46.86364 26.25
29   y 66.00000   male 46.86364 26.25
30   y 39.00000   male 46.86364 26.25
31   y 59.00000   male 46.86364 26.25
32   y 96.00000   male 46.86364 26.25
33   y 41.00000   male 46.86364 26.25
34   y 23.00000   male 46.86364 26.25
35   y 20.00000   male 46.86364 26.25
36   y 26.00000   male 46.86364 26.25
37   y 69.00000   male 46.86364 26.25
38   y 28.00000 female      NaN    NA
39   y 35.00000 female      NaN    NA
40   y 96.00000 female      NaN    NA
41   y 87.00000 female      NaN    NA
42   y 82.00000 female      NaN    NA
43   y 70.00000 female      NaN    NA
44   y 68.00000 female      NaN    NA
45   y 26.00000   male      NaN    NA
46   y 12.00000   male      NaN    NA
47   y 46.86364   male      NaN    NA
48   y 18.00000   male      NaN    NA
49   y 46.86364   male      NaN    NA
50   y 46.86364   male      NaN    NA
51   y  3.00000   male      NaN    NA
52   y 46.86364   male      NaN    NA
```

mean for `x` for male before female=42
mean for `y` for male before female=51

Comment: Having 2 `group_by` in a row means the first one is cancelled, unless you add `add = FALSE`. You should apply the `rleid` function after grouping by `add`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
data %>%  
  group_by(add) %>%                                           # for each add do the below...
  mutate(group2 = rleid(group)) %>% 
  group_by(add, group, group2) %>%
  mutate(MEAN = mean(x1[group=="male" & group2==1]),               
         Q25 = quantile(x1[group=="male" & group2==1], 0.25)) %>%
  group_by(add) %>%                                            # for each add update x1 values....
  mutate(x1 = ifelse(group=="male" & group2==3 & x1 > unique(Q25[!is.na(Q25)]), unique(MEAN[!is.na(MEAN)]), x1)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-group2) %>%
  data.frame()
```

Comment: AntoniosK, may i ask you to check this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52005153/select-group-before-certain-observations-separated-by-grouping-var-in-r-with-na. It is your script, but it has trouble with NA. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

As the accepted answer is already using the `rleid()` function from the `data.table` package I suggest to benefit also from the *update by reference by group*

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)[, rleid := rleid(group), by = add][
  rleid == 1L, `:=`(mean = mean(x1), Q25 = quantile(x1, 0.25)), by = add][
    , rleid := NULL][]
```

> ```
>     add x1  group     mean  Q25
>  1:   x 14   male 42.27273 21.0
>  2:   x 15   male 42.27273 21.0
>  3:   x 36   male 42.27273 21.0
>  4:   x 53   male 42.27273 21.0
>  5:   x 95   male 42.27273 21.0
>  6:   x 56   male 42.27273 21.0
>  7:   x 53   male 42.27273 21.0
>  8:   x 10   male 42.27273 21.0
>  9:   x 39   male 42.27273 21.0
> 10:   x 27   male 42.27273 21.0
> 11:   x 67   male 42.27273 21.0
> 12:   x 25 female       NA   NA
> 13:   x 19 female       NA   NA
> 14:   x 49 female       NA   NA
> 15:   x 53 female       NA   NA
> 16:   x 64 female       NA   NA
> 17:   x 61 female       NA   NA
> 18:   x 12 female       NA   NA
> 19:   x 75   male       NA   NA
> 20:   x 34   male       NA   NA
> 21:   x 88   male       NA   NA
> 22:   x 43   male       NA   NA
> 23:   x 85   male       NA   NA
> 24:   x 93   male       NA   NA
> 25:   x 44   male       NA   NA
> 26:   x 31   male       NA   NA
> 27:   y 37   male 51.45455 31.5
> 28:   y 90   male 51.45455 31.5
> 29:   y 66   male 51.45455 31.5
> 30:   y 39   male 51.45455 31.5
> 31:   y 59   male 51.45455 31.5
> 32:   y 96   male 51.45455 31.5
> 33:   y 41   male 51.45455 31.5
> 34:   y 23   male 51.45455 31.5
> 35:   y 20   male 51.45455 31.5
> 36:   y 26   male 51.45455 31.5
> 37:   y 69   male 51.45455 31.5
> 38:   y 28 female       NA   NA
> 39:   y 35 female       NA   NA
> 40:   y 96 female       NA   NA
> 41:   y 87 female       NA   NA
> 42:   y 82 female       NA   NA
> 43:   y 70 female       NA   NA
> 44:   y 68 female       NA   NA
> 45:   y 26   male       NA   NA
> 46:   y 12   male       NA   NA
> 47:   y 58   male       NA   NA
> 48:   y 18   male       NA   NA
> 49:   y 76   male       NA   NA
> 50:   y 93   male       NA   NA
> 51:   y  3   male       NA   NA
> 52:   y 31   male       NA   NA
>     add x1  group     mean  Q25
> ```