# select group before certain observations separated by grouping var in R with NA control

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

My sample.

```
 data=structure(list(add = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("x", 
"y"), class = "factor"), x1 = c(14L, 15L, 36L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 53L, 
10L, 39L, 27L, 67L, 25L, 19L, 49L, 53L, 64L, 61L, 12L, 75L, 34L, 
88L, 43L, 85L, 93L, 44L, 31L, 37L, 90L, 66L, 39L, 59L, 96L, 41L, 
23L, 20L, 26L, 69L, 28L, 35L, 96L, 87L, 82L, 70L, 68L, 26L, 12L, 
58L, 18L, 76L, 93L, 3L, 31L), group = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L), .Label = c("female", "male"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("add", 
"x1", "group"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -52L))
```

In this data there is group variable (sex (male and female) I need get statistics mean and 25 percentile for ALL male which go before female. Male which after female, i don't touch. Also female i don't touch.
this is analysis split by group `x` and `y` from add column.
if for male that go after female value by x1 > than 25 percentile, which we calculated for male before female, then this value must be replaced by mean for male before female " Female category we dont' touch.

The solutuion of AntoniosK is very good

```
library(tidyverse)
library(data.table)

data %>%  
  group_by(add) %>%                                           # for each add do the below...
  mutate(group2 = rleid(group)) %>% 
  group_by(add, group, group2) %>%
  mutate(MEAN = mean(x1[group=="male" & group2==1]),               
         Q25 = quantile(x1[group=="male" & group2==1], 0.25)) %>%
  group_by(add) %>%                                            # for each add update x1 values....
  mutate(x1 = ifelse(group=="male" & group2==3 & x1 > unique(Q25[!is.na(Q25)]), unique(MEAN[!is.na(MEAN)]), x1)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-group2) %>%
  data.frame()
```

but now i want replace 0 value by x1 to Na.

```
data$x1[data$x1 == 0] <- NA
```

after it, when i un script, i get the **error**

> Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) :    Evaluation error: missing
>   values and NaN's not allowed if 'na.rm' is FALSE.

How to do, that script passed NA and work only with int value?

## edit

```
data=structure(list(add = c(11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 
                       11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 
                       11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 
                       11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 
                       11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 
                       11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 
                       11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 11202L, 11202L), x1 = c(NA, 
                                                                                       2L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, 1L, NA, NA, NA, 
                                                                                       NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
                                                                                       NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 3L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, 1L, NA, NA, 
                                                                                       NA, NA, NA), group = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                                                                                                        2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                                                                                                        2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
                                                                                                                        2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("female", 
                                                                                                                                                                                        "male"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("add", "x1", "group"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           -52L))

library(tidyverse)
library(data.table)

data %>%  
  group_by(add) %>%                                          
  mutate(group2 = rleid(group)) %>% 
  group_by(add, group, group2) %>%
  mutate(MEAN = mean(x1[group=="male" & group2==1]),               
         Q25 = quantile(x1[group=="male" & group2==1], 0.25)) %>%
  group_by(add) %>%                                           
  mutate(x1 = ifelse(group=="male" & group2==3 & x1 > unique(Q25[!is.na(Q25)]), unique(MEAN[!is.na(MEAN)]), x1),
         x1 = ifelse(x1==0, NA, x1)) %>%  # new code added
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-group2) %>%
  data.frame()
```

## Edit2

result of code

```
add x1  group   MEAN    Q25
x   14.00000    male    23.72727    5.0
x   15.00000    male    23.72727    5.0
x   36.00000    male    23.72727    5.0
x   0.00000 male    23.72727    5.0
x   0.00000 male    23.72727    5.0
x   0.00000 male    23.72727    5.0
x   53.00000    male    23.72727    5.0
x   10.00000    male    23.72727    5.0
x   39.00000    male    23.72727    5.0
x   27.00000    male    23.72727    5.0
x   67.00000    male    23.72727    5.0
x   25.00000    female  NaN NA
x   19.00000    female  NaN NA
x   49.00000    female  NaN NA
x   53.00000    female  NaN NA
x   64.00000    female  NaN NA
x   61.00000    female  NaN NA
x   12.00000    female  NaN NA
x   23.72727    male    NaN NA
x   23.72727    male    NaN NA
x   23.72727    male    NaN NA
x   23.72727    male    NaN NA
x   23.72727    male    NaN NA
x   23.72727    male    NaN NA
x   23.72727    male    NaN NA
x   23.72727    male    NaN NA
```

After

```
add x1     group
x   94.90   male
```

sum of first 4 male after female=94.90

Comment: One of your column names is "how this analysis split by group?group". I can't see any column `ReturnCount` in `data`. And I can't see any zero values anywhere when I run that code.

Comment: ReturnCount is x1.

Comment: I think it will be easier if you post an example where `x1` has zeros so we can check why you get that error.

Comment: @AntoniosK, i edited post with zero. please check

Comment: @AntoniosK, i provided it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've added a piece of code that would solve your issue and a brief explanation of the error.

**Updated code**

```
data=structure(list(add = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("x", 
"y"), class = "factor"), x1 = c(14L, 15L, 36L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 53L, 
10L, 39L, 27L, 67L, 25L, 19L, 49L, 53L, 64L, 61L, 12L, 75L, 34L, 
88L, 43L, 85L, 93L, 44L, 31L, 37L, 90L, 66L, 39L, 59L, 96L, 41L, 
23L, 20L, 26L, 69L, 28L, 35L, 96L, 87L, 82L, 70L, 68L, 26L, 12L, 
58L, 18L, 76L, 93L, 3L, 31L), group = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L), .Label = c("female", "male"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("add", 
"x1", "group"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -52L))

library(tidyverse)
library(data.table)

data %>%  
  group_by(add) %>%                                          
  mutate(group2 = rleid(group)) %>% 
  group_by(add, group, group2) %>%
  mutate(MEAN = mean(x1[group=="male" & group2==1]),               
         Q25 = quantile(x1[group=="male" & group2==1], 0.25)) %>%
  group_by(add) %>%                                           
  mutate(x1 = ifelse(group=="male" & group2==3 & x1 > unique(Q25[!is.na(Q25)]), unique(MEAN[!is.na(MEAN)]), x1),
         x1 = ifelse(x1==0, NA, x1)) %>%  # new code added
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-group2) %>%
  data.frame()
```

**Error explanation**

You have to run the previous part of the code and in the end you just update the `x1` column. You get that error because `NA` values break the `mean` and `quantile` calculations you need to do.

An alternative way would be to update `x1` in the beginning and then use `na.rm=T` for your calculations.

For the **new case** you mentioned, where you start with `NA` values for `x1` try this:

```
data %>%  
  group_by(add) %>%                                          
  mutate(group2 = rleid(group)) %>% 
  group_by(add, group, group2) %>%
  mutate(MEAN = mean(x1[group=="male" & group2==1], na.rm = T),      ## extra code here ##    
         Q25 = quantile(x1[group=="male" & group2==1], 0.25, na.rm = T)) %>%  ## extra code here ##
  group_by(add) %>%                                           
  mutate(x1 = ifelse(group=="male" & group2==3 & x1 > unique(Q25[!is.na(Q25)]), unique(MEAN[!is.na(MEAN)]), x1))%>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-group2) %>%
  data.frame()
```

For the **new case** (edit 2) you mentioned, first save the output of the previous code as `data2`:

```
data2 = data %>% ...
```

And then run this:

```
data2 %>%
  group_by(add) %>%                           # for each add value                      
  mutate(group2 = rleid(group)) %>%           # created group2
  filter(group=="male" & group2==3) %>%       # keep only male after female
  summarise(SUM = sum(x1[row_number() <= 4])) # get sum of x1 for first 4 rows

# # A tibble: 2 x 2
#   add     SUM
#   <fct> <dbl>
# 1 x      94.9
# 2 y     107.
```

Comment: AntoniosK, is your code work on my data? I get the Evaluation error: missing values and NaN's not allowed if 'na.rm' is FALSE.

Comment: Yes, it should run, I've posted the whole thing now. Start a new R session and run just the code above. It should run. Then check with your whole dataset.

Comment: i edited post with new data. I got the error Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: missing values and NaN's not allowed if 'na.rm' is FALSE. can you check please edited data and explain why on it, it doesn't work?

Comment: You don't have zeros in column `x1`, but `NA`s. This dataset has a completely different philosophy compared to the previous example you posted. Before, we applied the process and, at the end, we changed zeros to `NA`. Now you have `NA`s from the beginning. You should try the alternative method I described. Use `na.rm=T`. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: AntoniosK,No, but I will be grateful if you show me how to use the alternative

Comment: using your code in another variant, i got the error. na.rm- doesn't work. What i should do? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52233504/na-rm-function-doesnt-work-if-use-more-then-1-group-in-r?noredirect=1#comment91416000_52233504