# na.rm function doesn't work if use more then 1 group in R

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, lapply

In this post 
[select group before certain observations separated by grouping var in R with NA control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52005153/select-group-before-certain-observations-separated-by-grouping-var-in-r-with-na), when using one group `add` `na.rm=T` works.
But new data, where three groups

```
data=structure(list(add = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "x", class = "factor"), 
    x1 = c(0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
    1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), add1 = c(514L, 514L, 
    514L, 514L, 514L, 514L, 514L, 514L, 514L, 514L, 514L, 514L, 
    514L, 514L, 514L, 514L, 514L, 514L, 514L, 514L, 514L, 514L, 
    514L, 514L, 514L, 514L, 514L, 514L, 514L, 514L, 514L, 514L, 
    514L, 514L, 514L, 514L, 514L, 514L, 514L, 514L, 514L, 514L, 
    514L, 514L, 514L, 514L, 514L, 514L, 514L, 514L, 514L, 514L
    ), group = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("female", 
    "male"), class = "factor"), add2 = c(2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 
    2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 
    2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 
    2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 
    2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 
    2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 
    2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L)), .Names = c("add", "x1", "add1", 
"group", "add2"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -52L
))
```

so when i run code

```
library(tidyverse)
library( data.table)
data %>%  
  group_by(add,add1,add2) %>%                                          
  mutate(group2 = rleid(group)) %>% 
  group_by(add,add1,add2, group, group2) %>%
  mutate(MEAN = mean(x1[group=="male" & group2==1], na.rm = T),      ## extra code here ##    
         Q25 = quantile(x1[group=="male" & group2==1], 0.25, na.rm = T)) %>%  ## extra code here ##
  group_by(add,add1,add2) %>%                                           
  mutate(x1 = ifelse(group=="male" & group2==3 & x1 > unique(Q25[!is.na(Q25)]), unique(MEAN[!is.na(MEAN)]), x1))%>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-group2) %>%
  data.frame()
```

i get error

```
Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Column `x1` must be length 24 (the group size) or one, not 0
```

PS. I just provided  one example to give data structure, cause there are 1000 groups. I can't find group 
from which there is  error

how to fix this error.

Comment: your code works well, without any error for me

Comment: @Salman, right, because i don't know how find problem group

Comment: i have more then 1000 group from 400 000 row, how can i find problem groups?, i just gave structure of mydata.

Comment: @Salman there is group var (sex. male-frmale) the data structure is that the first goes male then female and then male again, another can't be. male->female->male!!! for example john-julia-bill, john is male which go before female(julia")/  Do you understand?

Comment: i suggest you to add this link, to the previous question and tag "AntoniosK"

Comment: @Salman, i asked AntoniosK. But maybe you can help me find the group with this error Column `x1` must be length 24 (the group size) or one, not 0. I'd delete it from analysis

Comment: It's extremely likely that your problem is caused by what @Uwe mentioned in his answer below (i.e. all values for 1st male group are `NA`). How do you want to treat those cases, where the `mean` and `quantile` values are `NA`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, the error is caused by a first male group where *all* `x1` are `NA` in the first section (`group == 1L`).

IMHO, a cleaner approach is to compute the statistics for all groups first as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52036210/3817004) and to use a a non-equi join to update the affected rows in the second male group as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52038391/3817004).

```
library( data.table)
grp_stats <- setDT(data)[, group2 :=rleid(group), by = .(add, add1, add2)][
  group2 == 1L & group == "male", 
  .(group2 = 3L, mean = mean(x1, na.rm = TRUE), q25 = quantile(x1, 0.25, na.rm = TRUE)), 
  by = .(add, add1, add2)] 
grp_stats
```

> ```
>    add add1 add2 group2 mean  q25
> 1:   x  514 2018      3  1.5 1.25
> 2:   y  515 2018      3  NaN   NA
> 3:   z  516 2018      3  2.0 2.00
> ```

The groups which produce wrong statistics can be cleary identified. It's up to the OP to remove the affected groups from the dataset.

However, for the subsequent join we can leave them in as they will not have any affect.

The column `group2` with the constant value `3` already has been added to the group statistics to simplify the subsequent `update in a non-equi join`:

```
data[, x1 := as.numeric(x1)][
  grp_stats, on = .(group2, add, add1, add2, x1 > q25), x1 := mean][]
data
```

> ```
>     add  x1 add1  group add2 group2
>  1:   x 1.0  514   male 2018      1
>  2:   x 2.0  514   male 2018      1
>  3:   x  NA  514 female 2018      2
>  4:   x  NA  514 female 2018      2
>  5:   x 1.5  514   male 2018      3
>  6:   x 1.0  514   male 2018      3
>  7:   y  NA  515   male 2018      1
>  8:   y  NA  515   male 2018      1
>  9:   y  NA  515 female 2018      2
> 10:   y  NA  515 female 2018      2
> 11:   y 7.0  515   male 2018      3
> 12:   y 1.0  515   male 2018      3
> 13:   z 2.0  516   male 2018      1
> 14:   z  NA  516   male 2018      1
> 15:   z  NA  516 female 2018      2
> 16:   z  NA  516 female 2018      2
> 17:   z 2.0  516   male 2018      3
> 18:   z 1.0  516   male 2018      3
> ```

Note that rows 5 and 17 have been updated while the rows of the second group which produced the wrong statitistics haven't been touched.

`x1` is coerced to type `numeric` before joining to match the type of the result returned by `mean()`.

#### Sample data

Here is a sample data consisting of three groups. In the seocnd group, all `x1` values of the first male section are `NA`.

```
data <- data.table::fread("
add x1 add1  group add2
x    1  514   male 2018
x    2  514   male 2018
x   NA  514 female 2018
x   NA  514 female 2018
x    7  514   male 2018
x    1  514   male 2018
y   NA  515   male 2018
y   NA  515   male 2018
y   NA  515 female 2018
y   NA  515 female 2018
y    7  515   male 2018
y    1  515   male 2018
z    2  516   male 2018
z   NA  516   male 2018
z   NA  516 female 2018
z   NA  516 female 2018
z    7  516   male 2018
z    1  516   male 2018
")
```

#### Verify error message is caused by an all-NA first male group

When above sample dataset is piped into OP's code we can reproduce the error message:

```
library(dplyr)
data %>% 
  group_by(add,add1,add2) %>%                                          
  mutate(group2 = rleid(group)) %>% 
  group_by(add,add1,add2, group, group2) %>%
  mutate(MEAN = mean(x1[group=="male" & group2==1], na.rm = T),      ## extra code here ##    
         Q25 = quantile(x1[group=="male" & group2==1], 0.25, na.rm = T)) %>%  ## extra code here ##
  group_by(add,add1,add2) %>%                                           
  mutate(x1 = ifelse(group=="male" & group2==3 & x1 > unique(Q25[!is.na(Q25)]), unique(MEAN[!is.na(MEAN)]), x1))%>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-group2) %>%
  data.frame()
```

> Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) :
>     Column `x1` must be length 6 (the group size) or one, not 0